# how can I do this with the variables in lua?

Tags: lua

How can I make the 2 "print" give me true?

**Code:**

```
Config = {}
Config.option1.general = true
Config.option2.general = false

print(Config.option1.general)
print('Config.'..'option1'..'.general')
```

**Output:**

```
true
Config.option1.general
```

Excuse me for my ignorance

Comment: please specify why the second `print`should be different?

Comment: the objective was to create a function to which you give the option and execute a code with the variables of the corresponding list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *The objective was to create a function to which you give the option and execute a code with the variables of the corresponding list.*

Just create a function that takes as input an option string, and use the string as a key into the `Config` table:

```
function getOption (opt)
  return Config[opt].general
end
```

Then you can use the returned value however you like:

```
> getOption('option1')
true
> print(getOption('option1'))
true
> if (getOption('option1')) then print 'Yay!' else print 'Aw...' end
Yay!
```

If you want to live dangerously, you can use [`load`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-load) to run a chunk of code from a string. Using this feature with user input is begging for security problems, though.

Just write a function that takes a string specifying the option, and use that input to fashion a string representing the chunk. The `load` function returns a function that has the chunk as its body, so you will need to call that returned function to get the result from the chunk:

```
function getOption (opt)
  local cmd = 'Config.' .. opt .. '.general'
  return load('return ' .. cmd)()
end
```

With `getOption('option1')`, the `cmd` string becomes `'Config.option1.general'`, and this is concatenated with `'return '` to create the chunk `'return Config.option1.general'` which is passed to `load`. The statement `load('return Config.option1.general')()` calls the function returned by `load`, and the returned value is returned again from the `getOption` function.

Sample interaction:

```
> getOption('option1')
true
> getOption('option2')
false
```

Answer (score 0):

the first print is **collecting a variable** and therefore displaying the value of this variable

the second print is already **collecting a STRING**. A string is a set of characters, they represent only text, and therefore that text will be displayed

for example, imagine that we have a variable `test = true`

if you do `print(test)`, the value of the variable will be displayed, that is, `true`. Now, if you get `print("test")`, the `""` means that we are talking about a text "test", not the variable `test`, so `test` will be displayed instead of `true`.

Note that in the second print, 2 dots `..` are used, this is called CONCATENATION, it is when we join two or more strings, that is, two or more texts in one

For this reason there is no way you print `true` on the second print, because you are collecting a STRING with the name of the variable, and not the variable itself

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll try another way to do it.